# pcsdが起動できません。

Tags: linux

Centos7.1でLinuxHAJAPANのPacemaker-1.1.14-1.1 リポジトリパッケージをインストールして
HAを構築しようとしたところpcsdが起動出来ません。
インストール完了表示と起動コマンド、エラーメッセージは以下になります。

```
インストール:
  pacemaker-all.noarch 0:1.1.14-1.1.el7                                                                                                       

依存性関連をインストールしました:
  OpenIPMI-libs.x86_64 0:2.0.19-11.el7  cluster-glue.x86_64 0:1.0.12-2.el7  crmsh.x86_64 0:2.1.5-1.el7    openhpi-libs.x86_64 0:3.4.0-2.el7 
  pm_crmgen.noarch 0:2.1-1.el7          pm_diskd.x86_64 0:2.2-1.el7         pm_extras.x86_64 0:2.2-1.el7  pm_logconv-cs.noarch 0:2.2-1.el7  
  pssh.noarch 0:2.3.1-5.el7            

完了しました!
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# systemctl start pcsd
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# systemctl status pcsd
● pcsd.service - PCS GUI and remote configuration interface
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/pcsd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 水 2016-08-24 22:32:04 JST; 6s ago
  Process: 9929 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruby -C/var/lib/pcsd -I/usr/lib/pcsd -- /usr/lib/pcsd/ssl.rb > /dev/null & (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 9929 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 8月 24 22:31:58 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started PCS GUI and remote configuration interface.
 8月 24 22:31:58 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting PCS GUI and remote configuration interface...
 8月 24 22:32:01 localhost.localdomain abrt[9929]: detected unhandled Ruby exception in '/usr/lib/pcsd/ssl.rb'
 8月 24 22:32:04 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: pcsd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 8月 24 22:32:04 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit pcsd.service entered failed state.
 8月 24 22:32:04 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: pcsd.service failed.
 8月 24 22:32:04 localhost.localdomain ruby[9929]: /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot l...Error)
 8月 24 22:32:04 localhost.localdomain ruby[9929]: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 8月 24 22:32:04 localhost.localdomain ruby[9929]: from /usr/lib/pcsd/ssl.rb:5:in `<main>'
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Answer (score 1):

バージョン 1.1.13 のころに試したのですが、pcsd がまともに動きません。

- sinatra-contrib, open4, orderedhash, rpam を gem install する必要
- /etc/init.d/pcsd は ruby をバックグラウンドで起動しない
- /etc/sysconfig/pcsd で「export RACK_ENV=production」が必要
- /usr/sbin/corosync-objctl が無い (ここで諦めた)

linux-ha では crm コマンドを使った設定方法を推奨しているので、linux-ha のパッケージを使うのであれば pcs/pcsd は使わずに crm でセットアップするといいと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとう御座いました。現在crmで構築